# django orm - use query as subquery in from clause

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Let's assume the following postgres query:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (article) *
    from articles a
    where product = 'T-Shirts') a
order by min_price
```

How can I establish this in Django ORM?

using `Article.objects.[filters].distinct('article')` will force me to do `.order_by('article', 'min_price')` which results in the wrong query.

Thanks in advance.